Edit hex to point to dword (Hex Patch Porting IDA)
Just for starters I am new to IDA so I am very clueless
I am trying to port a hex patch part of this patch is that it points to a dword in each version the location of this dword changes meaning the hex needs to change, below is an asm view in IDA of what is looks like
xor     eax, eax
mov     cs:dword_1809C4474, eax
nop
nop
nop
nop
nop

note the
mov     cs:dword_1809C4474, eax
as in each version that changes
also here is the hex version of the asm above
31 C0 89 05 DD 83 7D 00 90  90 90 90 90
Using the same hex as above this is the asm view in the new version
xor     eax, eax
mov     dword ptr cs:stru_1809D4504.PrologOff, eax
nop
nop
nop
nop
nop

I need to change
mov     dword ptr cs:stru_1809D4504.PrologOff, eax
to
mov     cs:dword_1809EB414, eax
what is the new dword for this version but now the thing I am confused on is how do I do that from my understanding I need to change the hex for it to be like that but I am not sure what to change the hex to
any help is appreciated

89 denotes a mov r/m32, r32 and thus is followed by a modRM byte (0x05 in this case). 0x05 either means disp32 (in protected/compatibility mode) or rip-relative addressing (in long mode). If the former is true, you are probably just copied the wrong opcodes (89 05 DD 83 7D 00 is mov [0x7d83dd], eax). If the latter is true, you are actually looking at mov [rip+0x7d83dd], eax and you need to properly encode the offset as the difference between your target address and the end of the instruction (this difference is usually fixed, no matter where the binary is loaded).

Thanks but are you able to explain how I would go about
properly encode the offset as the difference between your target address and the end of the instruction
as I said I am new to this stuff
